# Inflationary (no total coin limit) cryptocurrency where miners keep all new coins

Tags: alternatives, currencies, mining-reward, inflation

Is there an inflationary cryptocurrency with following features?

1. No fixed limit on total coins (coins will be emitted forever).
2. Miners are the only source of new coins.
3. Mining reward (new coins) go all to miners.

I found several inflationary ones like Freicoin or Devcoin, but they seem to have various hybrid models where newly mined coins are (at least partially) transferred to other subjects than miners (various foundations, developers etc.).

Answer (score 1):

PPCoin and its offspring NovaCoin have an infinite money supply - even though the reward for blocks gets diminished over time (as in Bitcoin et al.), as the money supply increases there will be more and more coins offered as reward for simply hoarding the coin.

There are also built-in deflationary mechanisms for *destroying* coins with every transaction, so hopefully the money-supply would self-adjust: increasing or expanding as needed, depending on how much it's actually used.

Answer (score 1):

GRouPcoin is an inflate-forever coin (50 coins per block forever, not halving/halting like multiple others) and all proceeds go to miners.

http://devtome.com/doku.php?id=groupcoin

It is the predecessor of Devcoin.

Rarely used but has recently been one pool mining it (bitparking).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that I misunderstand your question, because as it is written and as I read it, there is a well-known answer: Bitcoin. Whilst not commonly described as inflationary, it is inflationary in the sense that, for now, new Bitcoin are created. In the Bitcoin protocol,

1. Miners are the only source of new Bitcoin, as these are only generated as block rewards. All other ways of receiving Bitcoin only transfer them rather than generating new ones. For example, the transaction fees earned by miners are not newly generated Bitcoin but rather come from someone else who has "paid" them. Likewise, when you buy Bitcoin, you pay someone for their Bitcoin, which previously existed and were their Bitcoin.
2. All new Bitcoin (the block rewards) are all distributed to miners only.

Again, if this is not the answer you are looking for, please clarify what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Though I thought inflationary as in total amount of coins ever in existence - so there should be no limit on total nr. of coins. Edited the question to clarify.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! And sorry that I cannot name such a virtual currency. Good luck finding it!